# JSON Parsing simple mistake?

Tags: java, android-studio

This is my code parse JSON data

```
 String finalJson =  buffer.toString();
 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(finalJson);
 JSONArray jaraay = jobj.getJSONArray("weather");
 JSONObject finalobj = jaraay.getJSONObject(0);
 String temp = finalobj.getString("temp");
```

And this the JSON data

```
{
"coord":{
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
 },
"weather":[
{
      "id":300,
      "main":"Drizzle",
      "description":"light intensity drizzle",
      "icon":"09d"
}
],
"base":"stations",
"main":{
     "temp":280.32,
     "pressure":1012,
     "humidity":81,
     "temp_min":279.15,
     "temp_max":281.15
      },
```

I would like to access the temp value that is inside base:stations:main but am quite sure on how to get the temp value using my code. Any Suggestions? Help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: so many typos, sorry to anyone reading this ^^*i am not quite sure on how to get the temp value using my code*

Comment: As per provided JSON structure, `main` is not inside `base`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access temp

String temp = jobj.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp");

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't a valid JSON . The one below is a valid one.

```
   {
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.13,
        "lat": 51.51
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 300,
        "main": "Drizzle",
        "description": "light intensity drizzle",
        "icon": "09d"
    }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 280.32,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "humidity": 81,
        "temp_min": 279.15,
        "temp_max": 281.15
    }
}
```

To access temp :

JSONObject mainObj = jObj.getJSONObject("main");

**String temp = mainObj.getString("temp");**